# SEO - Drop down menus using href="#"

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, seo, hyperlink

I've got a wordpress website with a drop down menu in the main navigation. The menu items does not link to anywhere, but rather on hover, the drop down menu displays. This is a pure CSS drop down menu.

Using the wordpress menu editor, I've assigned the URL as #, so in other words the html will be:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

If the user clicks this link, the URL will change to the current page's URL with a # added at the end. But the page does not refresh or reload in anyway.

The other option is to leave the URL blank in the wordpress menu system, meaning the html will be:

```
<a>Link</a>
```

This does not allow you to click the link and doesn't even change the pointer cursor to the hand as you'd expect on links.

Now, seeing as neither of these actually link anywhere, which would be best from a SEO angle?

Will google try to index all of my pages twice with the /# added at the end and causing duplicate content issues?

Thanks in advance.
Kind Regards
Willem

Comment: Forget SEO. It simply doesn't make sense to present visitors with links that go nowhere, so don't do it. (Don't use an `<a>` element at all for that matter).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, I would prefer to simply use a list item without the <a> tag, but the <a> tag is added by the wordpress menu editor, I only have these two options.

Comment: Don't be a slave to your CMS'. Wordpress is open source.

Comment: So what would you suggest?

Comment: Change it so it doesn't force you to use anchors for your non-link headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willem, 
Yes. According to Google www.example.com and www.example.com/# are different pages. This can lead to duplicate content penalties and can cause your links to be divided between pages as users link to both. I would recommend a different setup 301 redirect to the page without the #. There are some simple WP plugins that allow redirects to be setup in minutes without requiring use of the htaccess. Personally, I use the plugin called SEO Redirect 301s.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue.

Both variants ( `<a href="#">` and `<a>` ) do the same to your SEO: They are ugly from a Webdevelopers perspective, but they don't actually hurt your site or rankings. Google won't even crawl the URL '/#'. The only negative aspect is that you have more (worthless) links per URL and therefore less power to spend for the important URLs.

**My personal view**

Example 1:

- Imagine your Homepage has a "Linkpower" value of 100. (Yes, thats a term without meaning.)
- You have 2 links on your Homepage.
- So every link passes a Linkpower of 50.
  (Of course that's wrong, but is just to illustrate the problem.)

Example 2:

- Imagine your Homepage has a "Linkpower" value of 100.
- You have 3 links on your Homepage. (Including 1 worthless link for the Dropdown-Menu.)
- So every link passes a Linkpower of 33.

So, remove the odd links if you want to build the perfect website, or keep them if you have something better to do respectively if you want your menu to work in outdated browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `button` instead of `a`